# Cloud Firestore: Can I unsubscribe from all snapshot listeners at once?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can I unsubscribe from all Firestore snapshot listeners at once?

e.g. when the user logs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDKs for both Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore don't provide a way to automatically unsubscribe from active listeners.  Your client code should be doing that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can maybe push each subscriber to an array somewhere in your application context, and on sign-out iterate over the array, calling the un-subscriber function within each array index.